# Declare Matrix-like variable in apex with NXN dimensions

Tags: apex, developer-console, matrix

I'm creating a class where I have come to the conclusion that the most efficient method to proceed is with an array variable that works as a matrix. I'm not sure how many columns or rows I will need so it can't have a specific length or size.

Is there a way to declare a variable that works as a matrix?

Example:
Variable[Row Number, Column Number]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a 2-dimensional list by using a `List<List<Object>>`.  Entries should then be retrievable with a two bracket syntax, e.g.:

```
List<List<integer>> doubleList = new List<List<Integer>>();
for(integer i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    doubleList[i] = new List<integer>();
    for(integer j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        doubleList[i].add(j);
    }
}
System.debug(doubleList[1][2]);
```

You can nest more than two lists if you need a 3D or 4D array, though per [sfdcfox's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161407/how-deep-can-nested-maps-go-and-how-do-i-properly-add-data-to-those-nested-maps) there is a limit of 7 levels of nesting.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: FYI, there is a limit of 7 levels of nesting... see [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161407/how-deep-can-nested-maps-go-and-how-do-i-properly-add-data-to-those-nested-maps) for details.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks, I suppose if you had a requirement for more than 7 levels you could use a `Map<String, Object>` where the map keys were `n,m,z,...`

Comment: @IllusiveBrian It depends on the use case. By the time you get to the seventh level, you'll find that the code would be painful to even write, much less maintain. Two possible choices might be `Map<CustomKey, Value>`, where CustomKey is a class that implements hashCode/equals, or you might even do a `Map<Object, Object>`, where the value may be yet another `Map<Object, Object>`, as long as you need. The compiler limits you to seven levels, but using Object is a way to get further, it just requires more discipline. A simple string might work, too, but depends on the use case.

Comment: @sfdcfox The code being painful to write is pretty much true whichever method you use.  Also, I'm a bit surprised that getting around the limit using an `Object` doesn't throw a runtime error.